# Select All SubCategory Checkboxes When Parent Category CheckBox Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Hii I have an HTML Page which displays the category and their respecting sub categories with a checkbox beside every category. My list looks somewhat like this :-

Folder1
  --Folder2
  --Folder5
  --Folder8

Folder3
  --Folder4
  --Folder9

What i need is to check all the sub categories when the parent category is clicked. 
 (i.e Folder2,Folder5,Folder8 should get selected when the checkbox beside Folder1 is  checked)

Comment: Could you please provide the markup code snippet that is not working?

Comment: I didn't add any code to get the check box selected . Do you want the PHP code that fetches the List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit of a vague question so here are a couple of examples

Based on a class, check the parent if any child is selected, check ALL children if a parent is checked.

```
var checkboxHandlerObj = {
    init: function () {
        $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.parentClicked);
        $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class^="parent-"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.childClicked)
    },
    parentClicked: function () {
        var parentCheck = this.checked;
        $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').each(function () {
            this.checked = parentCheck
        });
    },
    childClicked: function () {
        var temp = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
        var parentId = temp[1];
        $('#' + parentId)[0].checked = $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"]:checked').length !== 0;
    }
}
checkboxHandlerObj.init();
```

a fiddle for that:http://jsfiddle.net/gfDAh/

and here is a parent dependance model where if ANY child is unchecked, it unchecks the parent, and it has a "check all children" box

```
$('#jobTypesMaster').click(function() {
    var iam = this.checked;
    $('.billdetail').each(function() {
        this.checked = iam;
    });
    if (!iam) {
        $('.billfinal:checkbox')[0].checked = iam;
    };
    $('.billfinal').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    if (!iam) {
        $('.billspaid:checkbox')[0].checked = this.checked;
    };
    $('.billspaid').attr('disabled', $('.billfinal').checked);
});
$('.billdetail').click(function() {
    if ($('.billdetail:checked').length < $('.billdetail:checkbox').length) {
        $('.billfinal:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
        $('.billspaid:checkbox')[0].checked = false;
        $('.billfinal').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.billspaid').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#jobTypesMaster')[0].checked = false;
    }
    else {
        $('.billfinal').attr('disabled', false);
    };
});
$('.billfinal').click(function() {
    $('.billspaid:checkbox').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
    if (!this.checked) {
        $('.billspaid')[0].checked = false;
    };
});
$('.billdetail').trigger('click'); //set value based on initial checked count
```

Fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/h682v/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually how to find the checkboxes that belong to a such subcategory.

Give the subcategory checkboxes the same name (eg `subcat_folder1`).
For the category checkbox, plase a javascript function on the `onClick` handle.
When the user clicked on the folder1 checkbox, find all elements with the name subcat_folder1 (`getElementsByName('subcat_folder1')`)and do your thing.

Comment: I totally agree with you george. Kindly look at this website and you can get an idea of what i am trying to get.

http://www.company-solution.com/dm/index.php?area=main&interface=users&sort_by=1&sort_order=ASC&page=1&return_to=@list&act=edit

Comment: I can not take a look at the website, i am getting a Permission Deny message on the screen.